# How to raise an float number to big integer?

Tags: php, math

I tried to do something like that:

```
$total = 0;
for ($j = 0; $j < 1000; $j++) {
    $x = $j / 1000;
    $total += pow($x, 1500) * pow((1 - $x), 500);
}
```

**$total** is 0.

PHP can't work with too small float values. What can I do? Which libraries can I use?

Comment: try [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to handle large numbers

Comment: why big integer?  your values are in `< 0.0 , 1.0 >` range so you need better precision floating variables with as much mantissa bits as possible ... the final `sum <= 1000` so you do not need too much exponent bits for this. Btw ideal is to use fixed point like `32.1568 bits` for this.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
f(x) = x^1500 * (1-x)^500
```

has (logarithmic) derivative

```
f'(x)/f(x)=d/dx log(f(x))
= 1500/x - 500/(1-x)
```

which is zero for

```
x0 = 3/4
```

having the maximum value of

```
f(3/4) = 3^1500/2^4000 = exp(-1124.6702892376163)
       = 10^(-488.4381005764309) 
       = 3.646694848749686e-489
```

Using that as reference value, one can now sum up

```
f(i/1000)/f(3/4)=exp(1500*log(i/1000)+500*log(1-i/1000)+1124.6702892376163)
```

giving a sum of `24.26257515625789` so that the desired result is

```
24.26257515625789*f(3/4)=8.847820783972776e-488
```

---

A practical way to compute such a sum would be to compute the list of logarithms (more python than PHP, look up the corresponding array operations)

```
logf = [ log(f(i/1000.0)) for i=1..999 ]
```

using the transformed logarithm of `f`, `log(f(x))=1500*log(x)+500*log(1-x)`.

Then compute `maxlogf = max(logf)`, extract the number `N=floor(maxlogf/log(10))` of the decimal power and compute the sum as

```
sumfred = sum([ exp( logfx - N*log(10) ) for logfx in logf ])
```

so that the final result is `sumfred*10^N`.